# Oddity: "grep" cmd in /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, grep

While digging through the birds-nest of network initialisation in our embedded linux setup (Linux SDK on Leopardboard SBC) we've come across what seems like an odd and possibly non-functioning line in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
# Wired or wireless interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
        pre-up /bin/grep -v -e "ip=[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+" /proc/cmdline > /dev/null
```

Now, the kernel cmdline in this system **may** contain the line "ip=192.168.2.1" or some other address, but this line specifically *ignores* it if it matches (**grep -v** = show non-matching lines only). Also, it's redirecting it to /dev/null, so it would seem futile either way.

Has anyone seen something like this or got any ideas what it could be doing / might be intended to do, other than *nothing*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man interfaces`:

```
       pre-up command
          Run command before bringing the interface up.  If  this  command
          fails then ifup aborts, refraining from marking the interface as
          configured, prints an error message, and exits  with  status  0.
          This behavior may change in the future.
```

From there, I would guess that the command you quoted is basically a test, destined to abort the ifup and reconfiguring the interface, if there's already and `ip=...` line in `cmdline`.
The redirection to `/dev/null` is applied to the pre-up error message, not the grep.